# Multivariable calculus chain rule problem involving ohms law

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know I need to use chain rule, but not sure how to solve this:

> Ohm's Law states that $I=\frac VR$ which relates current $(I)$ with voltage $(V)$ and resistance $(R)$. Suppose the voltage is decreasing at $5$ volts/second while the resistance is decreasing at $2$ ohms/second. Find the rate of change of the current with respect to time when the voltage is $80$ volts and the resistance is $40$ ohms.

Comment: It is better to type your question than to post it as an image.  Text is searchable and loads faster.  Furthermore, it is not advisable to link to other sites when the information provided there can be put into the post.  External links can become broken, making the post useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dt}&=\frac{R\frac{dV}{dt}-V\frac{dR}{dt}}{R^2}\\
&=\frac{40(-5)-80(-2)}{40^2} \mbox{ampere}/s
\end{align}